# Как проверить модуль на совместимость с разными версиями CPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некий модуль на Python который хотелось бы протестировать на совместимость с разными версиями интерпретатора Python (CPython) - найти крайне низкую версию под которой этот модуль заработает корректно. Вручную понятно как сделать:

- Визировать код глазками, знать ченджлоги Python'а
- Настроить контейнер или виртуальную машину в которой установить все доступные версии Python и позапускать этот модуль.

А есть ли какой нибудь онлайн сервис или настроенный контейнер, виртуальная машина в который загрузил модуль и он указал минимальную версию Python'а для этого модуля? Или может есть модули на Python которые умеют определять?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что такие сервисы или утилиты есть. В общем случае нерешаемая автоматически задача. Можно было бы анализом AST находить типичные проблемы несовместимости, но такая проверка не гарантирует 100% результата ([2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) косячит сильно). Другой вариант - это под нужной версией Python прогнать все execution path кода модуля, но когда автоматика научится этому, программисты начнут терять работу. А пока этого не произошло, авторы кода должны сами писать тесты, проверять совместимость и указывать её в документации.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой скрипт, интерпретатор покажет минимальную версию и выкинет AssertionError

```
import sys
l = []
for l1 in range(1, 4):
    for l2 in range(1, 10):
        l.append(tuple([l1, l2]))
l = l[:-3]
l = l[::-1]
print(l)
for versions in l:
    print(versions)
    assert sys.version_info.major == versions[0]
```

Comment: Я не понял этот код. Для чего нужно генерировать кортежи и сравнивать их с текущей версией Python? В моём вопросе проблема другая: Как узнать что некий код на Python корректно запустится на минимальной версии Интерпретатора (CPython). Я немного изменил сейчас текст моего вопроса, чтобы он был более однозначен.

Comment: Не могу объяснить почему, но `sys.version_info` это не одно и то же, что `sys.version`, а именно проверка кода на версию (вероятно, это недостаток документации), поэтому и тестируется через assert все существующие версии по убывающей через генерацию кортежей